# Code doesn't throw error but data not added

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I have a form that allows user to update and also create new entries to database, I am able to update but not create. The following is dal

```
if (actionrequired == Crud.Modify)
{
                    t_ProvisionSetup setupToBeChanged = (from p in Entities.t_ProvisionSetup
                                                         where p.ProvisionSetupId == provision.ProvisionSetupId
                                                         select p).Single();
                    setupToBeChanged.ModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    setupToBeChanged.ModifiedBy = userId;
                    setupToBeChanged = MapSetupToEntity(provision, setupToBeChanged);
                    Entities.SaveChanges();
                    setupid = setupToBeChanged.ProvisionSetupId;
}

if (actionrequired == Crud.Add)
{
                    t_ProvisionSetup setupToBeChanged = new t_ProvisionSetup();
                    setupToBeChanged = MapSetupToEntity(provision, setupToBeChanged);
                    setupToBeChanged.ModifiedBy = userId;
                    setupToBeChanged.ModifiedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    setupToBeChanged.CreatedBy = userId;
                    setupToBeChanged.CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;

                    Entities.SaveChanges();
                    setupid = setupToBeChanged.ProvisionSetupId;
}
```

It runs fine no errors but won't create new record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you need something like this?

```
Entities.t_ProvisionSetup.Add(setupToBeChanged);
```

before calling Entities.SaveChanges().